# Escape apostrophes from variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following script set up, and it works as intended....except for users with apostrophes in their email.

```
$users = get-content C:\Filename.csv

$results = Foreach ($user in $users)
{

get-aduser -filter "EmailAddress -like '$user'" -properties CanonicalName,LastLogon,Name | 
select Name,@{N="Thing";E={$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')[-4]}},@{N="Place";E={$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')[-5]}},@{N="Last Logon";E `
={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.Lastlogon)}}

}


$results | Export-Csv C:Filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Does anyone know how to escape the apostrophe in an email like `example_o'connor@example.com`? Whenever I run the above script it always errors out on email addresses like the one above.

Edit: My csv file is a single column of email addresses with no header.

Edit 2: Sorry to waste everyone's time. Turns out the script was working fine, along with some of the suggestions in this thread such as adding "" "" around my variable, but it was that I was testing against a list where not all the values were correct so that is my fault. Thank you everyone for your time.

Comment: Googling "get-aduser Escape apostrophes" shows several relevant answers e.g. [Get-Aduser -Filter will not accept a variable](//stackoverflow.com/q/20075502) i.e. `"EmailAddress -like ""$user"" "`

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the response. I had looked at other forums before posting here in regards to my apostrophe issue. I also tried those other solutions. The link you provided in your post does not deal with apostrophes though, and I ran into the issue they had before and found the same solution that was edited into the first post as the answer, which did fix my initial issue. I am still having issues though with the script not being able to parse apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Since you are using a CSV, I imagine you've piped them from another AD cmdlet.

Get-Member is a great tool here.

$users | Get-Member will output TypeName: CSV:Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser

However, this is not a String type which the Filter parameter in ADUser needs.
So to convert this...

$selection | Get-Member will output TypeName: System.String.

The other portion is to make sure that the -Filter parameter in Get-ADUser is expanding the strings properly one-by-one, since Get-ADUser's -Filter parameter cannot deal with String Arrays.

```
$users = Import-Csv C:\filename.csv
$selection = ($users.emailaddress)

foreach ($user in $selection)
   {
     get-aduser -filter {EmailAddress -eq $user} -properties CanonicalName,LastLogon,Name |`
     select Name,@{N="Thing";E={$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')[-4]}},`
     @{N="Place";E={$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')[-5]}},`
     @{N="Last Logon";E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.Lastlogon)}}
   }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain how your answer solves the OP's problem.

Comment: I should have, have now edited in, said that my .csv file is a single column of email addresses with no header to it. I think the suggestion offered may have worked in the scenario where a upn was used.

Comment: Just curious, where are you pulling the data from to create the CSV? And why are you not using a header in the CSV?

Comment: I'm pulling it from a report by our messaging admins, and the report itself has no headers. I do not have access to this data either, aside from a google sheet that was provided to me with said information. I'm trying to not use a header so that I could give this script to someone else if they were given the same information without explaining much to them aside from changing where to pull the csv from and where to store it.